# Overloading custom string operator += in c++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am working to recreate the various c++ types in order to better understand how they work. I am currently stuck on the += operator and can not find what the issue is with my declaration. Here is the code for my Class:

```
class String {
    int size;
    char * buffer;
public:
    String();
    String(const String &);
    String(const char *);
    int length(){return size;};

    friend bool operator==(const String &, const String &);
    friend bool operator<=(const String &, const String &);
    friend bool operator<(const String &, const String &);
    friend ostream & operator<<(ostream &, const String &);

    char operator[](const int);
//  friend String operator+=(const String &,const char * p);
    friend String operator+=(const char * p);

};
```

I am getting these to work as planned with the exception of the += operator defined as:

```
String operator+=(const char * p){
int p_size = std::char_traits<char>::length(p);
int new_size = size+p_size;
char * temp_buffer;
temp_buffer = new char(new_size);

for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
    temp_buffer[i] = buffer[i];
}

for(int i=size, j=0; j<p_size;i++,j++){
    temp_buffer[i] = p[j];
}

delete buffer;
buffer = new char[new_size];
size = new_size;
for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
    buffer[i] = temp_buffer[i];
}
return *this;
}
```

My errors are 
string.h:29: error: âString operator+=(const char*)â must have an argument of class or enumerated type
string.cpp:28: error: âString operator+=(const char*)â must have an argument of class or enumerated type

Any info of what I am doing wrong during overloading is appreciated.

Comment: `+=` is usually a member, not a friend. (What would the operator apply to in your code?)

Answer (score 2):

`operator+=` is a binary operator and thus requires two operands (e.g. `myString += " str",`, where `myString` and `" str"` are the operands).

However, you have an ill-formed `operator+=`, as it only accepts a single argument. Note that your `operator+=` is a stand-alone function (not a class method), with it returning a `String` and accepting a single `const char*` argument.

To solve your problem, make  your `operator+=` a member function/method, because by then, you'll have an implicit `this` parameter, which will be used as the left hand side operand.

```
class String {
    ...
    String& operator+=(const char * p);
};
```

and its definition

```
String& String::operator+=(const char * p) {
   ...
   return *this;
}
```

Notice that you are now returning a reference to `*this`, and its return type changed to `String&`. These are in accordance to guidelines in [Operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4421706/1619294) .

***CRITICAL UPDATE:***

```
temp_buffer = new char(new_size);
```

Noooo! You are allocating a single `char` and initializing it to `new_size`, and that is not what you desire. Change it to brackets.

```
temp_buffer = new char[new_size];
```

Now, you are properly allocating an array of `new_size` number of `char`s. And please don't forget to `delete[]` all those you `new[]`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the += operator works with c-strings is that `std::string`s have an implicit conversion constructor from c-strings.

Since you already have a conversion constructor, you should just make a += operator that takes a `String`.

Comment: So for your suggestion, I would make the class header as (const String &) so that my argument is a string already?

Comment: I believe that Mark's solution is the real solution here. Critically that you do not include `String::` before the operator+= definition.